# How to add doneListener to TextArea in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

TextField has a method called `setDoneListener()` which allows performing some action using the keyboard search, enter or Done button.

How do I implement the same for TextArea or is there a way to make Textfield multiple rows when typing? Instead of the single line text that scrolls left.

I know that `putClientProperty("searchField", true);`, `putClientProperty("sendButton", true);`and `putClientProperty("goButton", true);` would place a button on the keyboard, but how do I add action this button for TextArea?

Comment: did you try ```addActionListener```? https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextArea.html#addActionListener-com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener-

Comment: `addActionListener` would be called when the TextArea lost focus and not when the Done button or search icon on keyboard is pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextField multi = new TextField();
multi.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
multi.setRows(4);
multi.setColumns(20);
multi.setDoneListener(doneListener);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`JTextArea.setLineWrap(boolean wrap)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap-boolean-) method might be what you're looking for.

> Sets the line-wrapping policy of the text area. If set to true the lines will be wrapped if they are too long to fit within the allocated width. If set to false, the lines will always be unwrapped. A PropertyChange event ("lineWrap") is fired when the policy is changed. By default this property is false.

Comment: No, I need an actionListener on the virtual keyboard done button, this is codename one specific.

Comment: While the code *"gives what he asked for"*, providing it with no context (and in fact even *asking a question* in your *answer*) is not recommended. You should, for example, include a quote of, and a link to, *documentation*, explaining *how* and/or *why* that code is correct (if it is). In fact, here, I'll do it for you...